# Run animation after other animation

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

See http://jsfiddle.net/BNMpC/ for a working example.

I've basically got these orbs that grow and shrink on and off of hover.  I've also got them "nudging" around the other orbs.  When you over one at a time, and let all of the animations complete, it works great.

The problem is when you hover over many quickly-- the "nudging" doesn't work correctly. I was using `.filter(':not(:animated)')` to make sure the grow and shrink animations did not get interrupted, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is when a new orb gets hovered, you will need to end the animation of the previous one and reset; before starting the new animation sequence. *Or* try to let the DOM handle your "nudging" for you (keep the orbs in the layout flow, and let the resizing move the elements around it).

Answer (score 1):

If I got your questions correctly, set the next animation in a callback function

```
$(selector).animation('slow', function(){$(selector).animation();});
```

Comment: Uhh, that doesn't quite work because they need to run at the same time for the visual effect.